# create a server soap and forward requests to another soap server

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I used the [soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#soapcreateclientasyncurl-options---create-a-new-soap-client-from-a-wsdl-url-also-supports-a-local-filesystem-path) module to create a soap web server and it works well. Now, I want to forward the requests to another soap web server and I'm not sure how is the best way to do it.

Here is my soap web server listening on port 9090.

```
const express = require('express');
const soap = require('soap');

var myService = {
      MyService: {
          MyPort: {
              MyFunction: function(args) {
                  return {
                      name: args.name
                  };
              }
          }
      }
};

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('myservice.wsdl', 'utf8');

var app = express();


app.listen(9090, function(){
  soap.listen(app, '/myFunction', myService, xml, function() {
    console.log('server initialized... open http://localhost:9090/myFunction?wsdl');
  });


  soap.listen(app, '/foo', foo, foo, function() {
  });

  soap.listen(app, '/bar', bar, bar, function() {
  });

  // much more functions here...
});
```

My `myservice.wsdl`

```
<definitions name = "MyService"
             targetNamespace = "http://www.examples.com/wsdl/MyService.wsdl"
             xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:tns = "http://www.examples.com/wsdl/MyService.wsdl"
             xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <message name="MyFunctionRequest">
        <part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="MyFunctionResponse">
        <part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="MyPort">
        <operation name="MyFunction">
            <input message="tns:MyFunctionRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:MyFunctionResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name = "MyFunction_Binding" type="tns:MyPort">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="MyFunction">
            <soap:operation soapAction="MyFunction"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:MyService" use="encoded"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:MyService" use="encoded"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="MyService">
        <documentation>WSDL File for MyService</documentation>
        <port binding="tns:MyFunction_Binding" name="MyPort">
            <soap:address location = "http://localhost:8001/MyFunction/" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

The idea of this soap web server is to work as a proxy for an old server. Most of the requests we will simply forward to the old soap, and for a few, we want to intercept and run some logic before forwarding them too. The reason for doing this is that we can't touch the server/code of the old soap web server.

That being said, when I receive a request on `myFunction`, I want to forward the request to `myFunction` of http://oldServer:9090/myFunction?wsdl,

But I'm not sure how and where to instantiate the soap client. Here is my attempt of instantiating a client inside to forward the request, but that did not work.

```
const express = require('express');
const soap = require('soap');

var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://localhost:9090/ContentPrepServicePort?wsdl';

var myService = {
      MyService: {
          MyPort: {
              MyFunction: function(args) {
                
                var urlOldServer = 'http://oldServer:9090/myFunction?wsdl';
                
                soap.createClient(urlOldServer, function(err, client) {

                  // do something...

                  client.myFunction(args, function(err, result) {
      
                      return {
                        name: args.name
                      };
                  });
                });
              }
          }
      }
};

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('myservice.wsdl', 'utf8');

var app = express();


app.listen(9090, function(){
  soap.listen(app, '/myFunction', myService, xml, function() {
    console.log('server initialized... open http://localhost:9090/myFunction?wsdl');
  });

});
```